# Regular Expression to detect any combination of specified characters

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex pattern that will detect any combination of "m", "f", "h" or "t" within square brackets, upper or lower case. It should NOT return true if there are ANY other characters within the square brackets. For example, `[M]`, `[Fh]` or `[mT]` should pass whereas `[fa]` or `[z]` should fail.

The closest thing I've been able to come up with is `([[][FfMmHhTt]])` but this only checks for individual characters. I need it to check for any combination of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, and if you want to check for any number of these letters, just add the right quantifier:

```
^\[[FfMmHhTt]+\]$
```

This checks for a string which solely consists of `fmht`, either upper or lower case, in any order.

Comment: Thanks, just needed the plus sign. I'll accept your answer later since apparently I have to wait 10 mins...

Comment: Note that you also need to _escape_ literal square brackets (that is, assuming the input you expect is really surrounded by them).

Comment: No, they're literally supposed to be encased in square brackets.

Answer (score -1):

This expression might also work just OK, not sure though:

```
(?i)^\[[mfht]*\]$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/V4LG8O/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/V4LG8O/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.